# How to put some dynamic size links on a dynamic size image in html?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have an image with `class="img-responsive"` which has links on it.
The problem is, when size of image changes, the coords won't be in their correct places.

How can I have dynamic coords for links depend on the size of the dynamic image?

```
<img class="img-responsive" usemap="#image-map" src="/Content/Images/news/(8).png" alt="">
<map name="image-map">
     <area coords="419,64,15,179" shape="rect" href="" target="" alt="" title="">
     <area coords="13,184,420,277" shape="rect" href="" target="" alt="" title="">
     <area coords="14,283,420,374" shape="rect" href="" target="" alt="" title="">
     <area coords="13,380,418,473" shape="rect" href="" target="" alt="" title="">
     <area coords="14,481,419,572" shape="rect" href="" target="" alt="" title="">
</map>
```

Comment: Is the use of jquery possible?

Comment: hey, check that: https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/

Comment: @(A. Meshu) thanks, this worked.

Comment: @reporter yes it is, I'll be happy to learn other way(s) to do it

Answer (score 1):

Based on last comment from @ShareWin here a solution with Jquery.

Years ago, I faced to the same challenge. Accedently I found an Jquery plugin that allows to change the coodinates, depends on the picture size. The plugin calls [jQuery RWD Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps).

Here some steps to get it work:

1. Take the orignal picture and create the area cords (I used Gimp for it)
2. Publish the original picture to your web project.
3. Import jquery and this plugin into your site.

Thereby the plugin does working, there are some restrictions.

Here an example code:

```
<div id="yourDivId" ...>
  <img src="yourImage" class="map" usemap="#nameofImagemap" id="elementid" ..>
  <map name="nameofImagemap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="x,x,x,x" alt="Tooltip" href="yourTarget" />
    ...
  </map>
</div>
```

The javascript call is as follow:

```
$( document ).ready(function()
    {  
        $('#yourDivId img').rwdImageMaps();
    }
```

Important note: Whenever the size of used picture changes by hand, you have to recreate the area map.